# How do you kill all child processes without killing the parent

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a script which runs a background process at the beginning, then towards the end needs to stop that background process and its children, THEN do some other tasks etc then return an error code if necessary. How do I do this? I have seen several examples of how to kill the whole tree including the parent process (eg `kill 0`) but I want the main script to continue running and return the right error code. E.g.:

```
./some_process_with_child_processes &
./do_stuff
kill $! # doesnt kill child processes!
./do_other_stuff
exit 5
```

Comment: Modify the program so that the parent ignores the signal but the parent does not/

Comment: Couple of immediate thoughts come to mind, without knowing anything about your code base, you could make sure that all of the child processes have a unique name related to the parent process, eg, everything is prefixed with foo_project_child_*, that way you can simply use pkill -f foo_project_child_*, to handle things, otherwise, are you opposed to using a data store like redis etc which you can query and figure out which processes you need to kill ?

Comment: I'd rather not do a global pkill on all foo_project_etc* instances if possible, i want this to be self-contained. i haven't looked into redis, i will now. @Ed How do I modify my shell script to not be killed but its child processes will be? That is my question.

Comment: @grasevski - Use `trap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Ed Heal's comment:

In the parent process, trap SIGTERM, eg

`trap "echo received sigterm" SIGTERM`

Then, when you want to terminate all the child processes, in the main script do

`kill -s SIGTERM 0`

The parent will also receive SIGTERM, but that doesn't matter, since it's trapped that signal.

You may also find it useful to set a trap for EXIT in the child processes so they can clean up when they receive SIGTERM.

You *could* send the child processes SIGKILL, but that's a bit brutal, and the child processes won't have a chance to do any clean up.

---

**edit**

Here are some scripts that illustrate how a parent script can kill its children individually, rather than en masse using `kill -s SIGTERM 0`.

**traptest**

```
#!/bin/bash

# trap test
# Written by PM 2Ring 2014.10.23

myname=$(basename "$0")
child=sleeploop
delay=${1:-5}
loops=${2:-5}

sig=SIGTERM 
# sig=SIGKILL 
# sig=SIGINT 

# killed=False

signal_children()
{
    killed=True
    for ipid in "${pids[@]}"
    do 
        echo "Sending $sig to $ipid"
        kill -s $sig $ipid
    done
}

set_INT_trap()
{
    msg="echo -e \"\n$myname received ^C, sending $sig to children\""
    trap "$msg; signal_children" SIGINT
}

trap "echo \"bye from $myname\"" EXIT

pids=()
for i in A B C;do 
    echo "running $child $i $delay ..."
    ./$child $i $delay  &
    pid=$!
#     echo -e "$child$i PID = $pid\n"
    pids+=($pid)
done
# echo "all child PIDs: ${pids[@]}"

echo "$myname PID = $$"
echo; ps; echo

set_INT_trap $sig
trap "echo $myname Received SIGTERM; signal_children" SIGTERM

echo "$myname sleeping..."
sleep 18 &
wait $!
echo "$myname awake"

[[ $killed != True ]] && { echo "$myname sending $sig"; signal_children; }

echo "$myname finished"
```

**sleeploop**

```
#!/bin/bash

# child script for traptest
# Written by PM 2Ring 2014.10.23

myname="$(basename "$0")$1"
delay=$2
loops=${3:-5}

set_trap()
{
    sig=$1
    trap "echo -e '\n$myname received $sig signal';exit 0" $sig
}

trap "echo \"bye from $myname\"" EXIT
set_trap SIGTERM
# set_trap SIGINT

#Select sleep mode
if false
then
    echo "$myname using foreground sleep"
    Sleep()
    {
        sleep $delay
    }
else
    echo "$myname using background sleep"
    Sleep()
    {
        sleep "$delay" &
        wait $!
    }
fi

#Time to snooze :)
for ((i=0; i<loops; i++));
do
    echo "$i: $myname sleeping for $delay"
    Sleep
done

echo "$myname terminated normally"
```

This even works if you want to pipe the output of `traptest`, eg try

`{ ./traptest; echo >&2 exitcode $?; } | cat -n`

Comment: The problem with this is that if I then pipe my script into another program eg head, tail etc. then these will be killed too and the return code will be 143. This makes it a hassle to get the correct return code from my script.

Comment: In that case, I think you'll need to save the PID of each of the parent's child processes so you can kill them individually.

Comment: This understanding was helpful / worked well for my use case where, script A was calling script B. Ignoring KILL in A by setting a trap and then issue a kill -- -$$ ensured that "everything" went away and I could loop Script B any number of times.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the value of `$!` (the child PID) right after

```
/some_process_with_child_processes &
pid=$!
./do_stuff
kill $pid
./do_other_stuff
```

Comment: this doesn't kill its child processes.

Comment: What is "its" here?  The children of the background job?  Normally a job will indeed kill its children when it dies.  If it is not doing so, perhaps it has "daemonized" itself or otherwise registered signal handlers in an adverse way.  The clean fix might be to modify the background job if this is so.  Can you do that?

Comment: I agree with you that the clean fix is to modify the background job to kill its processes. I'll try to do this, otherwise I'll give up and settle on a hacky solution like "kill 0".

Comment: unfortunately the other program is a crappy 3rd party script. I may have to fix/rewrite it, because it seems there is no simple way of telling other processes in the group (eg from a pipeline or surrounding shell) from the ones spawned by that script.

Comment: it would be nice if there was a self-contained way to simply wrap that crappy script, such that the wrapped script would kill everything the crappy script starts, but nothing else.

Comment: @grasevski: that's sort of what process groups are for, but if the called script or executable goes out of its way to create a new process group, it will opt itself out of this mechanism.  You might need something more like a "sandbox" to run it in.