# Interrupt command line execution in Fortran without killing main program

Tags: linux, fortran

I have a Fortran program that runs a series of identical calculations on a number of different input data. After doing these calculations the code then always writes a GNUplot script that does some diagnostic plotting (nothing too difficult) and runs it using `execute_command_line` in Linux.

This usually works well, but after some time I think there must be a memory leak of some kind that works cumulative, because the GNUplotting becomes slower and slower. At some point it virtually stalls.

My question is therefore: **Is it possible to interrupt the call to `execute_command_line` using the keyboard without killing the main Fortran program**? Needless to say, `CTRL-C` kills everything, which is not what I want: I want the main program to continue.

I have been playing with the optional flag `wait=.true.` but this does not help.

Also, I know that the memory leak has to be fixed (or whatever the cause is), but for now I would like to first see the diagnostic output.

Comment: pause statement...? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/6j4m0vnal/index.html

Comment: I doubt the OP meant this. BTW, PAUSE is a deleted feature.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540044/how-do-you-kill-all-child-processes-without-killing-the-parent  You must trap the signals in the main program.

Comment: I would prefer a C extension instead, see https://airtower.wordpress.com/2010/06/16/catch-sigterm-exit-gracefully/

Comment: I created an example, but I cannot test it, because in my shell it does not terminate the main program at all? Which OS and shell do you use?

Comment: Sorry Vladimir, I hadn't seen your previous comment.

I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I compile using gfortran (with C preprocessiong). The F program is run using mpirun.

Do you need more information?

Comment: It is better to put the solution in an answer, even if it is just a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I have been able to come up with is kind of a workaround:

- Modify the shell script so that it

  - runs the Fortran program in the background: `./mpirun prog_name options &`
  - gets the PID of this proces: `proc_PID=$!`
  - waits for the process: `wait $proc_PID`
  - traps an interrupt signal: `trap handler SIGINT`
  - lets the handler send a `SIGURS1` signal: `function handler() { kill -SIGUSR1 $proc_PID }`
- modify the Fortran code so that it catches the SIGUSR1 signal and does what you want with it. For example by having a look [here](https://www.sharcnet.ca/help/images/4/42/Fortran_Signal_Handling.pdf).

By running the `mpi` process in the background you avoid killing `mpirun` with `SIGINT`, which [cannot be trapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870738/a-custom-interrupt-handler-for-mpirun) but you send instead a `SIGURS1`, which is properly propagated to the `mpi` processes where it can be handled with directly.

As a side note, however, I realized that this will not solve my problem as my problem was related to an external call to `gnuplot` using `execute_command_line`. Since I had a cumulative memory leak, at some point this call started taking for ever because memory resources became scarcer. So the only thing I could have done is manually killing the `gnuplot` process.

Better, of course, was fixing the memory leak, which I did.