# Handle multiple signals in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh, embedded-linux, busybox

I have to handle two signals i.e. `EXIT` and `SIGTERM` in the shell script,
now I am handling it as follows in my script.
It works fine, However I want to know if there is better way of doing it?
Somehow I feel `trap '' EXIT` in case of `elif` is not right, is it okay that way ?

**This script will run in the Embedded Linux board which has busybox `shell(ash)` and not `bash shell`**

```
#!/bin/sh -eu

ERROR_MESSAGE=""
SIGNAL_TYPE=""

handle_error()
{

    if [ "${SIGNAL_TYPE}" = "EXIT" ];then
        if [ ! -z "${ERROR_MESSAGE}" ];then
            echo "Inside handle_error():${ERROR_MESSAGE}"
            exit 1
        fi
        echo "Normal exit"
    elif [ "${SIGNAL_TYPE}" = "SIGTERM" ];then
        echo "Aborted by SIGTERM signal"
        trap '' EXIT
        exit 1
    fi

}
trap 'SIGNAL_TYPE="EXIT";handle_error' EXIT
trap 'SIGNAL_TYPE="SIGTERM";handle_error' SIGTERM

ERROR_MESSAGE="Error inside whileloop"
count=1000
while [ true ];do
    count=$(( count - 1 ))
    echo "Inside while count=${count}"
    [ "${count}" -eq 0 ] && break
    sleep 2
done
ERROR_MESSAGE=""
exit 0
```

Any suggestion/pointer will help me with this.

Comment: you're already declaring `trap`s per signal, why not just echo the error message from the "body" of the trap code, ie `trap 'echo "Aborted by SIGTERM signal" ' SIGTERM` ?

Comment: You can add more than 1 signal name to the end of a trap def so you could have an `else` sort of trap that showed something happened (but without the specificity of which signal). Add a use case test you your Q so we can understand what your code is attempting to solve, and we may be able to make more useful comments ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for attention shellter. Actually I have to change multiple script to handle two signals. `EXIT` signal is used in case of any error. However we adding capability wherein script can be terminated by other script in some situation. I am planning to send `SIGTERM` signal in that case to script under execution. So as a first step I wrote this small script to understand trapping of multiple signal. Moreover requirement is we should be able to determine that by which signal script is exiting and take cleanup action accordingly.

Comment: well I'm not a `trap` guru, AND when you talk about "change multiple scripts" and "terminated by other script" etc., this is bordering on a day-rate consulting ;-)  This Q/A may give you some good pointers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540044/how-do-you-kill-all-child-processes-without-killing-the-parent/26549587#26549587 . Also searching for `[unix] OR [linux] bash [OR] ksh` returns a 100+ answers, that would be worth scanning thru. (That's how I found the included link). Wont' be able to help much more here, I hope someone else picks up Q. Good luck.

Comment: If your error handler isn't sharing any code across signals, just define a separate error handler for each signal. `trap 'handle_exit' EXIT`, `trap 'handle_term' SIGTERM`, etc.